# Barcode reader library for iOS

Tags: library, ios, camera, scanning, barcode

What options do we have as iOS developers to a library that enables scanning/reading a barcode through the device’ camera?

Commercial or gratis. Open source or closed.

Preferably works with Swift, or at least Objective-C.

No other features needed, just scan the barcode and translate to its textual value. From there my app will store in a database or send to a server and so on. Not creating or printing barcodes.

Answer (score 4):

Basil if you are looking for commercial iOS libraries for barcode recognition you can take a look at [LEADTOOLS Barcode SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/barcode). LEADTOOLS has native iOS frameworks for both Objective-C and Swift. You can take a look at this app store demo here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/leadtools-barcode-scanner/id601172795?mt=8

You can reference my answer on this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343677/how-to-read-barcode-information-from-an-uiimage-in-iphone/39419298#39419298). You can see the extent of required code using the SDK for both Objective-C and Swift:

Obj C:

```
data = [_barcodeEngine.reader readBarcodes:rasterImage searchBounds:LeadRectZero 
symbologies:enabledSymbologies options:_barcodeReadOptions error:&error];
```

Swift:

```
data = try? self.barcodeEngine.reader.readBarcode(rasterImage, searchBounds: LeadRectZero, 
symbologies: enabledSymbologies, options: self.barcodeReadOptions)
```

Please note: I am an employee of this product